# MS graph - List all the subsites in multi geo tenant via API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, graph-api, multi-geo

I am trying to list down all the sites in the multi geo tenant. I can able to list down only NAM PDL records via Graph API. I can't able to list down other PDL sites.

I tried following endpoints and nothing works,

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/?$search="](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/?$search=%22)" -  Empty results
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/?search=* (Can't able to get the other region sites)

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/getallsites - lists only base SharePoint site. I need subsites too.

Scope available: **Sites.Read.All**